# ERD when there is any details table

Tags: database, erd

I have two main table, for example Books and Members, A member can borrow some book in one time. So there is details table for relationship table borrows. But how can i draw it in ERD (Entity Relationship Diagram) ?

[image: How to draw this tables to ERD?]

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic many-to-many relationship. Each member can borrow many books. Each book may be borrowed by many members (not at the same time of course). So `borrow` table will be a junction table:

[image: many-to-many relationship]